# How can I have static functions list in .map file?

Tags: map-files

I'm using VS2012 and enabled the option /MAP to generate xxx.map file for debugging.
But all the static functions are not list in the .map file, how can I include all the static functions in the .map file?

Currently, I build the project in Debug mode.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find an answer?